# How to parse a value from an XML response which I got as a soap API response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

I got an XML response as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.*********.in">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:LoginResponse>
         <return>
            <SessionID>3AC46E3F62</SessionID>
            <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
            <ResponseMessage>Successful</ResponseMessage>
         </return>
      </ns1:LoginResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I parse the SessionID and ResponseCode from this xml using PHP.Im unable to do this.Please suggest some methods to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this : [How can I get and process a response from a PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179772/how-can-i-get-and-process-a-response-from-a-php-api/27179829#27179829)  and apply print_r(htmlentities($xmldata->asXML())); to your XML response

and this too : [soap:Envelope SOAP-ENV:Envelope PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770898/soapenvelope-soap-envenvelope-php)

the responses from there maybe will help you , of course you may code yourself cause is very easy

Check this code too is already working example (very close to your problem):

```
<?php

$a ='<soap-env:envelope xmlns:ns1="http://v3.core.com.productserve.com/" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:body>
    <ns1:getproductlistresponse>
      <oproduct>
        <iid>113133802</iid>
        <icategoryid>270</icategoryid>
        <imerchantid>1547</imerchantid>
        <iadult>0</iadult>
        <sname>The Ashes / 5th Test - England v Australia - Day 1</sname>
        <sawdeeplink>http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=113133802&amp;a=111402&amp;m=1547&amp;platform=cs</sawdeeplink>
        <sawthumburl>http://images.productserve.com/thumb/1547/113133802.jpg</sawthumburl>
        <fprice>119.99</fprice>
      </oproduct>
    </ns1:getproductlistresponse>
  </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>';



$xml = simplexml_load_string($a);


$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml->children($ns['soap-env']);
$getproductlistresponse = $soap->body->children($ns['ns1']);
foreach ($getproductlistresponse->children() as $item)
{
  //This example just accesses the iid node but the others are all available.
  echo (string) $item->iid . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: Np , I hope the example to help you